# What is the usefulness of BOOST_QUATERNION_ACCESSOR_GENERATOR?

Tags: c++, boost, quaternions

I am trying to read some boost headers to see how useful this may be. In particular, I started to read the quaternion.hpp file here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/boost/math/quaternion.hpp

What is the usefulness of the macro BOOST_QUATERNION_ACCESSOR_GENERATOR? What programming technique is that (if it is one)?

Comment: A reason to avoid this package? There are plenty of other good quaternion packages out there. This package is not one of those shining examples of Boost at it's best. This is downright ugly code for no good reason. It's not just the macros all over the place. Look at their norm! `real(q*conj(q))`? Seriously?

Comment: I thought that boost was made of high-quality C++ stuff... Thus quaternion package is just over-engineered?

Comment: Those atrocious macros are there because the authors didn't want to use templates. One reason for that is that Boost tries to work with lots of compilers, many of which do not fully support the C++03 standard. Templates are one of the weak points in many of those non-compliant compilers.

Comment: I see, thanks! Aiming at supporting a lot of compilers comes at the cost of source code intelligibility. Not sure I will go the boost way then. Thanks again.

Comment: @Korchkidu: Er, who cares if they use macros in their implementation? You're not going to with Boost because of it? You should care about the ease of use and results.

Comment: @GManNickG: not ok with that. Because we have a perfect example (after reading more) of an over-engineered useless library. They spent their time doing cool C++ stuff maybe. But failed in providing a usable/useful quaternion library.